# What's the difference between Verilog Test Fixture and Verilog Module ? And when to use them?

Tags: verilog

I just started to learn Xilinx ISE. I wanna know what's the difference between Verilog Test Fixture and Verilog Module ? And when to use them?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I know where you are coming from but your question is not 100% accurate.

- A test fixture is a piece of code to test another piece of Verilog code.
- A module is a basic unit of hierarchy in Verilog. 
  What you are probably referring to is what I would call a **hardware module**: A module which can be converted to hardware.

The test fixture itself is never intended to be converted to working hardware and therefore can use the full power of the HDL language. It can contain *non-RTL* code.

A **hardware module** can only use the RTL subset of the HDL languge.

If we are talking about *module* in general then that distinction is no longer possible! The test fixture often **is** a module itself and can contain other modules. Those other modules can be hardware modules or other test modules. Most likely it will contain the *hardware module* it is going to test. (Often referred to as DUT: Device Under Test)

As to when to use them;

- A test (module) is used to test other pieces of HDL code.
- A hardware module is piece of Verilog code you intent to convert to hardware

<sub>If you look a [This](http://www.verilog.pro) website. It is the only one I know that not only provides Verilog modules but also their testbenches.</sub>